# node.js error of callback function in

Tags: node.js

I am facing an error in my node.js code.

```
Error: /workspace/Ap/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:252
throw new Error(msg);
      ^
Error: .get() requires callback functions but got a [object Undefined].
```

Yesterday my code was working fine but today with same code i  face above error,
and I don't get where is the problem. My code is:

```
 app.js

 var express = require('express');

 var routes = require('./routes');

 var http = require('http');

 var path = require('path');

 var app = express();

 var mysql = require('mysql');
```

routes/index.js

```
module.exports = function(req, res){

  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });

};
```

Thanks..

Comment: Are you sure this is all your code? The error is in `router/index.js` at line 252. Show us that region of the code

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at where you define a GET route, likely at line 252 or thereabouts.

To process a GET in your framework, a callback must be supplied. Currently, your code is supplying `[object Undefined]`, which likely means your object, or exports or whatever is filling that function parameter isn't what you think it is! : )